# How should I test the composition of React components using HOCs (or should I even test them at all)?

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme, higher-order-components, recompose

Testing components with [HOCs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) generally seems to be a major problem ([enzyme#539](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/539), [enzyme#1002](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1002), [recompose#407](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/issues/407), ...). Most discussions include the opinion "test only the HOC as a function and then later not the usage", whereby for unit tests the actual component is exported as named export and tested in isolation. Then some workarounds are suggested (like `dive` until the component is reached and the like).

The technical implementation is accordingly also (relatively) clear to me, but it is now difficult for me how and whether the composition should be tested with the HOCs in the end.

example:

```
import withState from 'recompose/withState';

export const InnerMyComponent = /* ... */;

const enhance = withState('prop', 'setProp', null);

export const MyComponent = enhance(InnerMyComponent);
```

It seems very important for the app that withState is called correctly and give `prop` and `setProp` to the inner component. Should I always test accordingly that the two props are passed on correctly like

```
expect(shallow(<MyComponent />).dive().prop('setProp')).toBeDefined()
```

So, should I write tests like that or what would be a better way to test the composition of an app?

Answer (score 2):

To test or not to test an HOC might depend on which HOC are you using(whether its an HOC that is written by you or an HOC that is being imported from the library). If it is an HOC that is being imported from the library, its the responsibility of the library to write test cases for that HOC since it is the one that is exposing methods and props to you and hence should work correctly. On the other hand if there is an HOC that you have written, you should write test cases to verify whether it functions correctly in different scenarios.

In order to test the component which is wrapped with an HOC, the most easiest way is to test it by providing the props to the component that the HOC will provide when you are shallow mounting it like

```
const wrapper = shallow(<InnerMyComponent prop={null} setProps={jest.fn()} />);
```

and then test the behaviour of InnerMyComponent

Now when you have to test a custom HOC, you test it as a function passing some random component to it and checking whether the component receives those props and also testing the inner functions

Answer (score 0):

When unit testing a HOC, there are three main things that should be tested (if some parts of the HOC are very simple, these tests may not all be necessary). The examples below use Jest.

1) Props should be passed correctly to the inner component. This includes ones that the HOC creates or modifies, and ones that are passed straight through. For example:

```
    it("passes A prop to InnerMyComponent", async () => {
        // ...
        let container = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>).dive();
        const inner = container.find(InnerMyComponent).at(0);
        const { A } = inner.props();
        expect(inner.props().A).toEqual(expectedA);
    });
```

2) Lifecycle methods in the HOC work as expected. For example:

```
    it("calls X on mount", async () => {
        // ...
        spy = jest.spyOn(MyComponent.WrappedComponent.prototype, "X");
        const component = mount(
            <MyComponent {...props}/>
        );
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
        spy.mockReset();
    });
```

3) Non-lifecycle methods in the HOC work as expected.

```
    it("method P works", () => {
        // ...
        let container = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>).dive();
        let result = container.instance().P("input");
        expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
    });
```

Any further functionality will be either related to the inner component, and so should be tested there, or is in the realm of integration testing. As HOCs act as normal components, they should be able to be treated as such in integration tests.